# push json data to database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

So my site parses JSON data, and breaks it into separate stories from the NY Times API.

I'm trying to load those separate stories into my MySQL database.

The code below runs the page but getting an error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/topline/controllers/index.php

Line Number: 29
```

**Took out my api key below.**

**Model**

```
<?php

    class Api_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct() {

        } // End of construct

        public $offset;


        public function get_news() {


        $offset = 0;

        // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/mostviewed/all-sections/1.json?offset=" . $offset . "&api-key=mykey"); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch);      

        $Obj = json_decode($output);

        return $Obj;


        } // End of function

    } // End of class

?>
```

**View**

```
<section>
    <?php

    $paginate = site_url('/pageup');

    //loop through json response items  
    foreach ($articles->results as $article){

        //error reporting turned off for this process because some objects have more than 1 photo
        error_reporting(0);

        echo "<div class='story'>";
            echo "<div class='photo'>";
                //pass image into an img tag
                echo "<img src='" . $article->media[0]->{"media-metadata"}[0]->url . "' />";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='story-text'>";
                //call the story headline
                echo "<h3>" . $article->title . "</h3>";
                //call the description
                echo "<p>" . $article->abstract . "</p>";
                //call the link to the full story
                echo "<p class='btn btn-primary'><a href='" . $article->url .  "' target='_blank'>Read More</a></p>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

        //setup database array
        $article_data = array(
            'id' => 1,
            'image' => $article->media[0]->{"media-metadata"}[0]->url,
            'body' => $article->abstract,
            'title' => $article->title,
            'link' => $article->url         
        );
    }

    //var_dump($articles->results[0]);

    ?>  

    <p><a href="<?php echo $paginate; ?>" class="btn btn-block">Load More Stories</a></p>

</section>
```

Controller

```
<?php

    class Index extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct() {

            parent::__construct();

            session_start();

        } 

        public function index() {

            $data['title'] = "Topline Press";

            // Load the model
            $this->load->model('Api_model');

            // Call the method of the model
            $data['articles'] = $this->Api_model->get_news();

            // Load the views
            $this->load->view('header', $data);
            $this->load->view('start', $data);          
            $this->load->view('footer', $data);

            //push story data into database
            $this->db->insert('stories', $article_data);

        } 

    } // End of class

?>
```

Fairly new at this so I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the values before doing an insert into db:

```
$this->db->set('column_in_stories_table', $value_to_place_in_table); 
$this->db->insert('stories'); 

// Produces: INSERT INTO stories (column_in_stories_table) VALUES ('{$value_to_place_in_table}')
```

If you want, you can also store your model object into the db from your controller:

```
/*
    class Api_model {
        $title = 'My Title';
        $content = 'My Content';
        $date = 'My Date';
    }
*/

$obj = new Api_model;

$this->db->set($obj);
$this->db->insert('stories');
```

Comment: Yep - seem to have it working now. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @user2673468 if an answer is helpful and resolves your issue you should mark it as "accepted" by clicking the green check mark next to it, this let's the community know your problem is now solved